# Splitting a string - Python

Tags: python, string, split

I'm having trouble splitting a string, it keeps saying that option_convert and option_convert3 is not equal to dollar and pound

Code:http://pastebin.com/HFSW2BU2

Can't get it work here for some reason.

```
def option1():
    option_convert = input("""
What curreny would you you like to convert and convert to, (Example: dollar & pound) this would allow you to convert dollars to pounds.
""")
    option_convert2 = option_convert.split('&')[0]
    option_convert3 = option_convert.split('&')[1]
    print (option_convert2)
    print (option_convert3)
    if option_convert2 == "dollar" and option_convert3 == "pound":
        print ("test")
    else:
        print("Something went wrong...")
```

Comment: You can refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm and check examples given.

Answer (score 8):

```
dollar & pound
```

See the spaces before and after `&`. That is the culprit here.

```
`dollar ` != `dollar`
```

So, that condition will fail. We can use `strip` function to remove the the whitespaces (newline, space character, tab, linefeed) like this

```
option_convert2 = option_convert.split('&')[0].strip()
option_convert3 = option_convert.split('&')[1].strip()
```

See, you are splitting twice in this program. This can be optimized like this

```
option_convert2, option_convert3 = map(str.strip, option_convert.split('&'))
```

Comment: I've been noticing your fine regex, but looking at old answers I see that your even more amazing with python. Lots to learn from your answers, upvoting. :)

Comment: @zx81 Thank you :-) I am still learning a lot from Stackoverflow

Comment: wow, it's inspiring to hear that even on the mountaintop you are still learning. I'm stoked. :)